# GnuPG 2.2.4 file decryption issue with symmetric key

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am having issues attempting to decrypt a file that I previously encrypted using a symmetric key I created. I am using GnuPG 2.2.4, on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

To highlight part of the problem I created a file: test.ods

1. I can encrypt this file:  gpg -c test.ods
2. Strangely, I can decrypt using an unspecified action and I am not prompted for a phassphrase: gpg test.ods.gpg (return test.ods)
3. However if I specify the action it fails after entering the passphrase: gpg -c test.ods.gpg    or 
   gpg -d test.ods.gpg (the output is a long series of junk
   characters)

When typing, gpg -k, I can successfully see my key details on the keyring

I'm generally concered that I am not understanding how to use the gpg application. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> However if I specify the action it fails after entering the passphrase: gpg -c test.ods.gpg or gpg -d test.ods.gpg (the output is a long series of junk characters)

It doesn't fail. It simply outputs the encrypted or unencrypted content. You probably don't want a binary file shown on screen; you want to redirect it to a file.

Run `gpg -d test.ods.gpg > test.ods`. Note that this will overwrite whatever is present in `test.ods` without asking, or create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, makes sense and works. Without specifying the action, gpg must assume I want to redirected the decrypted information to test.ods